Uncaught (in promise) error when interacting with a smart contract
I’m using wagmi ^1.3.10 and
getting this error:
getTransaction.js:58 Uncaught (in promise) TransactionNotFoundError
    at getTransaction (getTransaction.js:58:15)
    at async delay.count.count (waitForTransactionReceipt.js:104:48)
    at async attemptRetry (withRetry.js:17:30)

when calling this function:
export const createProposalInteraction = async (
  ipfsHash: string,
  formAddress: string
) => {
  const { request: prepareConfig } = await prepareWriteContract({
    address: mainContractAddress,
    abi: MainContractAbi,
    args: [formAddress, ipfsHash],
    functionName: "createProposal",
  });
  const { hash } = await writeContract(prepareConfig);

  const data = await waitForTransaction({
    hash,
  });
  return data;

};

However, the transaction itself successfully passes.
Here is my wagmi config:
import {
  RainbowKitProvider,
  getDefaultWallets,
  connectorsForWallets,
} from "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit";
import {
  argentWallet,
  trustWallet,
  ledgerWallet,
} from "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/wallets";
import { configureChains, createConfig, WagmiConfig } from "wagmi";
import { sepolia } from "wagmi/chains";

import { publicProvider } from "wagmi/providers/public";

const { chains, publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(
  [
    sepolia,
  ],
  [
    publicProvider(),
  ],
  //{ retryDelay: 500 }
);

const projectId = "my project id";

const { wallets } = getDefaultWallets({
  appName: "RainbowKit demo",
  projectId,
  chains,
});

const demoAppInfo = {
  appName: "Rainbowkit Demo",
};

const connectors = connectorsForWallets([
  ...wallets,
  {
    groupName: "Other",
    wallets: [
      trustWallet({ projectId, chains }),
      ledgerWallet({ projectId, chains }),
    ],
  },
]);

export const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors,
  publicClient,
  webSocketPublicClient,
});

I’ve even tried to tinker with retryDelay in wagmi config , but that doesn't seem to be the issue.
How to fix this?

You should use waitForTransactionReceipt.
In your code corresponding to createProposalInteraction, replace:
const data = await waitForTransaction({
  hash,
});
return data;

With:
const transactionReceipt = await waitForTransactionReceipt(wagmiConfig, {
  hash
});
return transactionReceipt;


waitForTransactionReceipt is a function from wagmi version 2.
waitForTransaction was renamed to waitForTransactionReceipt.
is there a way to fix my error with wagmi version 1?

Can you try adding the timeout?

Thanks! It seems that the timeout fixed the issue.

UPD. issue was fixed for like 10 tries and then reappeared again

That’s weird though. You mean it worked fine for the first 10 transactions after you added timeout?

yes. not exactly 10, I didn't count, but for some reason it just stopped working after a while.
can it be related to Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript error i'm getting ?

I don’t think that’s causing the issue. Have you tried increasing the confirmations?

tried it, that doesn't fix the issue

Would it be possible for you to share the repo of your codebase, so that I can try debugging the same on my end?

sorry for the delay. here is the repo: https://github.com/RASHMOR1/Proposal-Based-Crowdfunding . blockchain interactions are in app/application/create-proposal, /components/ModalAccept, /components/ModalDeny, etc

ok, issue resolved by replacing publicProvider() in wagmiConfig with another provider; now it works fine.
